# How to display images from database in react expo

Tags: sqlite, react-native, compare, directory, expo

I have captured one image from camera then i stored in to folder(default image path) and database(image name),now i have to compare an image with folder and database.if it is same theni have to display image in gallery.if any one know means please let me know,in advance thanks.

here attaching my code please check it,
database:

```
display(){
      db.transaction(
        tx => {
        tx.executeSql('select * from gallery_images', [], (tx, results) =>
          console.warn(results)
        );
      },
    );
    }
```

folder images:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    const photos = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(PHOTOS_DIR);
    this.setState({ photos });
  };
```

Comment: please any one help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are using React Native, since you mention expo. I think I get what you need, first let's break down the problem.

1. You need to check two equal files, so you need to read them and get their properties. You can try properties-reader:

   npm install properties-reader

Here you can check file name, size, dimensions and whatever you need to compare with the other image.

2. You need to display the image, try import `expo`:

   var icon = this.props.compareSuccessful   ? require('./yourImage.png') : require('./default.png'); ;